# VB.NET webbrowser controller can't set value in textbox

Tags: vb.net, webbrowser-control

VB.NET webbrowser controller
can't set value in textbox

```
<input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtUsername" type="text" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtUsername" style="width:95%;" class="TextBoxWatermark" autocomplete="off">
```

more information

```
var Page_Validators =  new Array(document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_RequiredFieldValidator1"), document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_RequiredFieldValidator2"));
```

more information

```
document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_RequiredFieldValidator1').dispose = function() {
Array.remove(Page_Validators, document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_RequiredFieldValidator1'));
```

}

more information

```
Sys.Application.add_init(function() {
$create(AjaxControlToolkit.TextBoxWatermarkBehavior, {"ClientStateFieldID":"ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtUsernameWatermarkExtender_ClientState","WatermarkCssClass":"TextBoxWatermark","WatermarkText":"ตัวอย่าง mj99u53xxxxxxxx","id":"ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtUsernameWatermarkExtender"}, null, null, $get("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtUsername"));
```

});

and more

```
document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_RequiredFieldValidator2').dispose = function() {
Array.remove(Page_Validators, document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_RequiredFieldValidator2'));
```

}

i tried this code

```
webBrowser1.Document.All.GetElementsById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtUsername").SetAttribute("Value", "xxxxx");
```

it's can't work

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtUsername").SetAttribute("Value", "xxxxx");
```

Without the `All` property.

Comment: i'm tried your code but NullRefferenceException [Object reference not set to an instance of an object] occur

Comment: @sandra Are you sure `webBrowser.Document` is not `Nothing`? If its Nothing, your webpage is not loaded and you need to post more code to solve this.

Comment: i'm tried this code in my web it's work but i'm tried this code in another web i't not work  why?

Comment: @sandra Maybe the second web needs more time to load or a proxy is intercepting and changing the web because you dont have the cookies. Imposible to know without more information

Comment: Second web create by .aspx it's can protected  ?
and more code >>>>
`<input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtUsername" type="text" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtUsername" style="width:95%;" class="TextBoxWatermark" autocomplete="off">
<input type="hidden" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtUsernameWatermarkExtender_ClientState" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtUsernameWatermarkExtender_ClientState">
`

Comment: @sandra If you want to add code, edit your question and add it there. But this code gives no clue about your problem, you have to give more information.

Comment: @sandra your question right now is very unespecific. It could be a lot of problems. [Improve your question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) in order to have better answers.